# Redirect parent taxonomy to it's child

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy, redirect, htaccess

I am trying to redirect this

```
url/investments/state/city/
```

to this

```
url/investments/city/
```

custom post

- investments

taxonomy structure:

- state 1

  - city 1
  - city 2

and so on.

Any elegant solution?

Comment: Is "url" intended to be part of the actual URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `state` and `city` are variable path segments, so you are essentially redirecting `/investments/<one>/<two>/` to `/investments/<two>/` then try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect "/investments/<one>/<two>/" to "/investments/<two>/"
RewriteRule ^(investments)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2/ [R=302,L]
```

If you need any further explanation then just ask in comments.

**UPDATE:** I've added an end-of-string anchor (`$`) to the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in the above directive.

Comment: It works like a charm, thx mate :)

Comment: I was testing it for a while and as always there is a "but". pagination doesn't work, so going to /investments/city/page/2/ goes to 404, once rule is active.

Comment: @Mastafu Ah, I had missed the end-of-string anchor on the regex, so it was matching too much. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I love your regex knowledge ;) thx again.